# Ubuntu delayed startup (systemd-networkd-wait-online timeout)

Tags: networking, hostapd

I'm experiencing delayed startup caused directly by systemd-networkd-wait-online timeout (2 minutes). Could you help me diagnose this? Especially how to dig deeper in systemd-networkd-wait-online debugging maybe with some extra flags? So far I just know "some interface fails"... Apart from that delay router, wifi accesspoint and internet connection functions properly.

I know I can bypass this delay error adding "--any" flag to wait-online service, but I'm curious if this can be fixed without workarounds.

I'm using Ubuntu Server 22.04 with 6.2 Kernel
PC is configured as Router.
WAN connection is built-in RJ-45 NIC (logical name: wan-wire).
LAN is a bridge (logical name: lan-wifi-bridge) that consist of usb dongle NIC RJ-45 (logical name: usb-lan-wire) and hostapd Access point created with usb dongle (logical name: usb-wifi).

networkctl resutls after (delayed by 2 minutes) startup - see that usb-wifi is still in configuring status:

```
IDX LINK          TYPE     OPERATIONAL SETUP      
  1 lo            loopback carrier     unmanaged
  2 wan-wire     ether    routable    configured 
  3 usb-lan-wire ether    no-carrier  configured 
  4 lan-wifi-bridge   bridge   no-carrier  configured 
  5 usb-wifi      wlan     no-carrier  configuring
```

Journalctl logs (see the delay between 12:54:34 and 12:56:31 where 2 minute timeout occurs):

```
sudo journalctl -b | egrep -i networkd
Sep 11 12:54:30 thin systemd-networkd[599]: lan-wifi-bridge: netdev ready
Sep 11 12:54:30 thin systemd-networkd[599]: lo: Link UP
Sep 11 12:54:30 thin systemd-networkd[599]: lo: Gained carrier
Sep 11 12:54:30 thin systemd-networkd[599]: Enumeration completed
Sep 11 12:54:31 thin systemd-networkd[599]: lan-wifi-bridge: Link UP
Sep 11 12:54:31 thin systemd-networkd[599]: wan-wire: Link UP
Sep 11 12:54:31 thin systemd-networkd[599]: usb-lan-wire: Link UP
Sep 11 12:54:31 thin systemd-networkd[599]: lan-wifi-bridge: Gained carrier
Sep 11 12:54:31 thin systemd-networkd-wait-online[603]: managing: usb-lan-wire
Sep 11 12:54:31 thin systemd-networkd-wait-online[603]: managing: usb-lan-wire
Sep 11 12:54:31 thin systemd-networkd-wait-online[603]: managing: usb-lan-wire
Sep 11 12:54:31 thin systemd-networkd[599]: wlan0: Interface name change detected, renamed to usb-wifi.
Sep 11 12:54:31 thin systemd-networkd-wait-online[603]: managing: usb-lan-wire
Sep 11 12:54:31 thin systemd-networkd-wait-online[603]: managing: usb-lan-wire
Sep 11 12:54:31 thin systemd-networkd-wait-online[603]: managing: usb-lan-wire
Sep 11 12:54:32 thin systemd-networkd-wait-online[603]: managing: usb-lan-wire
Sep 11 12:54:32 thin systemd-networkd[599]: usb-wifi: Link UP
Sep 11 12:54:32 thin systemd-networkd-wait-online[603]: managing: usb-lan-wire
Sep 11 12:54:32 thin systemd-networkd-wait-online[603]: managing: usb-lan-wire
Sep 11 12:54:32 thin systemd-networkd-wait-online[603]: managing: usb-lan-wire
Sep 11 12:54:32 thin systemd-networkd-wait-online[603]: managing: usb-lan-wire
Sep 11 12:54:32 thin systemd-networkd-wait-online[603]: managing: usb-lan-wire
Sep 11 12:54:33 thin systemd-networkd[599]: lan-wifi-bridge: Lost carrier
Sep 11 12:54:33 thin systemd-networkd-wait-online[603]: managing: usb-lan-wire
Sep 11 12:54:33 thin systemd-networkd-wait-online[603]: managing: usb-lan-wire
Sep 11 12:54:34 thin systemd-networkd[599]: wan-wire: Gained carrier
Sep 11 12:54:34 thin systemd-networkd-wait-online[603]: managing: usb-lan-wire
Sep 11 12:54:34 thin systemd-networkd-wait-online[603]: managing: usb-lan-wire
Sep 11 12:54:34 thin systemd-networkd-wait-online[603]: managing: wan-wire
Sep 11 12:54:34 thin systemd-networkd-wait-online[603]: managing: usb-lan-wire
Sep 11 12:54:34 thin systemd-networkd-wait-online[603]: managing: wan-wire
Sep 11 12:56:31 thin systemd-networkd-wait-online[603]: Timeout occurred while waiting for network connectivity.
Sep 11 12:56:31 thin systemd[1]: systemd-networkd-wait-online.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 11 12:56:31 thin systemd[1]: systemd-networkd-wait-online.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 11 12:56:32 thin systemd[1]: Starting Dispatcher daemon for systemd-networkd...
Sep 11 12:56:32 thin networkd-dispatcher[628]: No valid path found for iwconfig
Sep 11 12:56:32 thin networkd-dispatcher[628]: No valid path found for iw
Sep 11 12:56:32 thin systemd[1]: Started Dispatcher daemon for systemd-networkd.
```

Hostapd is running as standard system service. Hostapd.conf crucial excerpt :

```
interface=usb-wifi
bridge=lan-wifi-bridge
```

And netplan configuration:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd

  ethernets:
    wan-wire:
      match:
        macaddress: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
      set-name: wan-wire
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      accept-ra: false
      link-local: []
      addresses:
        - 192.168.0.100/24
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
        search: []
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.0.1
    usb-lan-wire:
      match:
        macaddress: yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
      set-name: usb-lan-wire
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
    usb-wifi:
      match:
        macaddress: zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
      set-name: usb-wifi
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false

#BRIDGE IS EXTENDED BY HOSTAPD AT LATER STAGE
  bridges:
    lan-wifi-bridge:
      interfaces:
        - usb-lan-wire
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      accept-ra: false
      link-local: [ ]
      addresses:
        - 192.168.10.1/24
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
        search: [ ]
```